# Google setOnLoadCallback and Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, google-visualization

I am using ajax to hit a URL that serves Json through Node.js/Express. The Json is returned fine, and I have tested it. The data it receives should be plotted in a graph using Google Chart API (Which works fine if the array is hard-coded).

I am recieving 4 unexpected 'Uncaught typeErrors' and would appreciate being pointed in the right direction.

Your assistance is greatly appreciated, and welcomed!

[image]

**Here is the code in question (I think)**

```
 <!-- <script>
            var nData;
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:3000/renderedJson',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: [],
                success:function(data){
                nData = data;
                console.log("success");
                console.log(nData);
                }
            })
            .done(function() {
                console.log("done");
                getData();
            })
            .fail(function() {
                console.log("error");
            })
            .always(function() {
                console.log("complete");
            });
            });
        </script>
```

[Here is an example (with hard coded data, working! To see, comment the ajax request and uncomment the hardcoded variable)](http://jsfiddle.net/hm88ora5/)

Update - Here is my payload, working from the URL I setup through Express / Node (which makes a call to a MongoDB instance)

```
[{"_id":"559c27abe01e815c0f7b69d3","date":"2015-01-2","one":[{"a":9},{"b":8},{"c":7},{"d":6},{"e":5},{"f":4},{"g":3}],"two":[{"h":2},{"i":1}]},{"_id":"559c27abe01e815c0f7b69d2","date":"2015-01-1","one":[{"a":1},{"b":2},{"c":3},{"d":4},{"e":5},{"f":6},{"g":7}],"two":[{"h":8},{"i":9}]}]
```

**Update** After further debugging, I believe the following code is not firing off.

```
 google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
console.log('loaded google 1');
drawChart(cols, rows);
console.log('loaded google 2');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is undefined with the `getData()` function. The code you have currently posted is incomplete. Looking at your fiddle there is a line between `getData` and `drawChart` functions:
        `getData();`
that immediately calls your `getData` function before the ajax call has been completed. Remove this line and it should work.

- its very hard to see the errors on that picture.
- the errors on that
  picture relate to the places where the errors are happening so just
  showing your ajax isnt enough to debug the problem (just for furture
  reference)
- Its a good idea if things are undefined to check them
  within the function thats throwing the errors. In this case if you
  log `nData` within `getData` it will probably output `undefined` -
  which can lead to where the problem has originated.

**edit**

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['line']});
```

then instead of

```
google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['line']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    drawChart(cols, rows);
});
```

jus have:

```
drawChart(cols, rows);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, the line getData() was removed before I posted jsFiddle, my mistake. That line is not currently there and the error is still being thrown. I have updated question with new Fiddle, and put the getData function inside the "success" part of the ajax call. As for the errors,  the origin shows coming from 'chext driver' 'htsa common' 'content' and 'global-shortcut' and I have none of those files loaded. (they do not exist in my application), Even when the getData(); inside the 'done' portion of the ajax the result is the same.

Comment: Id imagine those files are part of googles files and that they are called when you are trying to draw the graph. What is logged if you have `console.log(nData)` within the `getData()` function?

Comment: Looking at your new fiddle - you are redeclaring nData multiple times. First, globally as a google data table, then locally as an empty array, then inside your function you are setting the global nData=data. I havent used this google api before but this doesnt look right. You should go back tot he old fiddle. Trying to comment and uncomment code in current fiddle is a nightmare.

Comment: I can log nData inside getData just fine, and the data is manipulated, I think it has to do with drawChart at this point then. I have fixed the variables, and commented the ajax (uncommented hardcoded json) please see new jFiddle

Comment: I believe google.setOnLoadCallback is not firing off.

Comment: I just tried that (apparently this question is asked a lot online) and the outcome was the same. The cols/rows are defined in the getData function.

Comment: I moved the following outside getData and the errors are gone, but the chart is not drawn.     google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['line']});

Comment: It doesn't look like drawChart is getting fired off, I threw logs and they aren't showing up.